# How to draw image using RGB?

Tags: java, ppm

I've got semi-working code here. I'm getting a bad draw, the image doesn't draw correctly. I'm reading into an array RGB values (ppm format). I'm not sure what I'm doing wrong, but here's my code & pic (its supposed to be a red Lancia Stratos) :

http://oi60.tinypic.com/20h91kk.jpg

```
package ppmHomework;

import java.awt.Color;
import java.awt.Graphics;
import java.awt.image.BufferStrategy;
import java.awt.image.BufferedImage;
import java.io.File;
import java.io.FileNotFoundException;
import java.util.Scanner;

import javax.swing.ImageIcon;
import javax.swing.JFrame;
import javax.swing.JLabel;

public class ReadImage {

public ReadImage() {

}

public static void main(String[] args) throws FileNotFoundException {

    int width, height, maxRGB;

    File file = new File("ppmImage.ppm");

    Scanner kb = new Scanner(file);
    kb.next();
    width = kb.nextInt();
    height = kb.nextInt();
    maxRGB = kb.nextInt();
    JFrame frame;
    BufferedImage img;

    int[] arrayImage = new int[width * height * 3];

    int j=0;
    while (kb.hasNextInt()) {
        arrayImage[j] = kb.nextInt();
        j++;
    }

    img = new BufferedImage(width, height,BufferedImage.TYPE_INT_RGB);
    int i = 0;
    for (int k = 0; k < width; k++) {
        for (int p = 0; p < height; p++) {
            System.out.println(arrayImage[i] + " " + arrayImage[i+1] + " " + arrayImage[i+2] + " " + i); 
                int col = new Color(arrayImage[i], arrayImage[i+1], arrayImage[i+2]).getRGB();
                img.setRGB(k, p, col);
                i+=3;
            }

        }
    frame = new JFrame("WINDOW");
    frame.setVisible(true);

    frame.add(new JLabel(new ImageIcon(img)));

    frame.pack();
    frame.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.DISPOSE_ON_CLOSE);


}
```

}
Any help is much appreciated...thanks

Comment: My guess is that you are mixing up a change in rows (height) and a change in columns (width). This happens a lot. Try changing the set RGB to: `img.setRGB(p, k, col);`. If this is correct, I can post it as an answer.

Comment: I would printout **everything** read in by the Scanner to help debug your problem. You look to be out of phase. Are you careful to skip PPM comment lines?

Comment: @Obicere nah, just tried it and it doesn't work.

Comment: @HovercraftFullOfEels there are no comment lines. The content of the file is PPM, followed by the width, height, max rgb color, and the rest are triplets of pixel in RGB

Comment: @stryk3r1215 I just made my own ppm test file, modified the program such that the first loop condition is `k < height`, `p < width` and `img.setRGB(p, k, col);` and that worked perfectly for me.

Comment: @Obicere it worked! I did just as you last suggested. I'm still dumbfounded, what's the problem exactly?

Answer (score 2):

The problem exists with the way data is stored in a 2D array. In a 2D array, `i` is a change of rows and `j` is a change of columns. We can then see the following:

```
      i
  +---------------> Change in columns
  | 4   7   8  10
  | 5   1  23   4
j | 8   2   1   0
  | 4   6   8   1
  |
  V Change in rows
```

When you set the loop condition to `k < height` for the first loop, you are stating that this will be done through the changing of rows.

When you set the loop condition to `p < width`, for the second loop (nested in the first), you are stating that this will be done through the changing of columns.

Thus, the (i, j) position of the point is actually in the form of (p, k) when using a Cartesian plane. This commonly gets mixed up.

So lastly, change the set RGB to: `img.setRGB(p, k, col);`.

Comment: If I could upvote, I would have. Thanks for the help and clarification!